# How to write controller spec for method which returns an object, but without checking for any related templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, rspec3

I would like to ask my question in more conslidated way with basic example.

```
1) I have UsersController
2) I have show method in it
3) But I don't have any templates for this method(either - show.html.erb/show.xml.erb etc)
4) So currently, I just wanted to write a spec for just checking whether my method is returning an object or not
5) it is working, but as it is CRUD related method, it is expecting a Template for it.
6) ActionView::MissingTemplate
```

I have tried in this way

```
it "should show the user record" do
  get :show, :id => 1
  User.should_receive(:find).at_least(:once).with(1).and_return(mock_user)
end
```

```
class UsersController
  def show
    # params = {}
    # params = {:id => 1}
    @user_obj = User.find(params[:id]) # ActiveRecord::Relation
  end
end

require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  def mock_user(stubs={})
    @mock_user ||= mock_model(User, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  it "should show the user record" do
    expect(assigns(:user_obj)).to eq(mock_user) # How to stop execution  here only.
  end
end
```

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template users/show with
>   {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html],
>   :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
>   "#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't seem right for me. 
This type of testing (controller tests is) for testing the response of action and rendering. so you shouldn't do that you should test the output of the rendering of the action. otherwise, if you wanted to test the method  `show` only (unit testing)
don't use `get` here you can do this

```
users_controller = UsersController.new
users_controller.show
```

and test it as any method inside any class

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. As you said, it is correct only, Actually we need the specs for testing its complete method and also to test for its renderings, but as the purpose code refactoring is happening for rails upgradation, they have removed unwanted methods and templates.

SO in such way I wanted to concentrate only on controller methods which returning any objetcs, but not working on its rending templates.

Comment: Thanks for giving the idea.

**I tried in this way, it is working.**

`it "should show the user record" do

    # expect(assigns(:user_obj)).to eq(mock_user) # How to stop execution  here only.

    User.stub(:find).with(1) { mock_user }

    controller.params[:id] = 1

    controller.show

    assigns(:user_obj).should be(mock_user)

  end`

Comment: Yeah it is write answer for me..!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a render, so it searches for template to render.

```
class UsersController
  def show
    # params = {}
    # params = {:id => 1}
    @user_obj = User.find(params[:id])
    render status: 200, json: @user_obj
  end
end
```

Now your spec shoud work.

Comment: Thanks for that, but currently I dont want to check any renedings I wanted to check only for methods returning objects and it is working in this way.

`it "should show the user record" do
  # expect(assigns(:user_obj)).to eq(mock_user) # How to stop execution  here only.
  User.stub(:find).with(1) { mock_user }
  controller.params[:id] = 1
  controller.show
  assigns(:user_obj).should be(mock_user)
end`

Comment: your spec will still work with the change mentioned. the render will prevent the template missing error and you can still check for assigns as I have assigned user object to @user_obj and it will be equal to the mock user